# How to prompt a user to open a file in Python

Tags: python, file

I'm using the following code to open a file based on the path set by the user, but am getting errors. Any suggestions?

```
f = raw_input("\n Hello, user. "
    "\n \n Please type in the path to your file and press 'Enter': ")
    file = open('f', 'r')
```

It says f is undefined or no such thing exists... even though I am defining it? Using 'r' to read the file.

Comment: You are opening file named f, *not* a file named by variable f. And by the way, you have the indentation wrong; this won't be accepted by python parser at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't have the `f` in quotes:

```
myfile = open(f, 'r')
```

`'f'` means the string consisting of the letter f so your code was looking for a file called `f` and not finding it.  Instead use `f` which means the value of the variable f.

Also, don't call the variable to store your file `file`.  This is easily done but try to avoid it.  There is already a built-in class called `file` and it's best practice not to hide any built-in classes or functions with your own names.  This is because other code you see will expect `file` to represent the file class and not your variable.

One way to see if a term is in use is to use the `help` function:

```
>>> help(file)

Help on class file in module __builtin__:

class file(object)
 |  file(name[, mode[, buffering]]) -> file object
 |  
 |  Open a file.  The mode can be 'r', 'w' or 'a' for reading (default),
 |  writing or appending.  The file will be created if it doesn't exist
```

And as indendation is significant in Python I'd recommend getting your indentation exactly right when posting code on here.

Comment: `file` is gone in Python 3 and really never used in modern Python 2, so why _not_ shadow it? I agree with the general rule, but `file` is an exception in my mind.

Comment: I use `file` in Python 2 because I consider `open` to be just plain wrong, no matter what the PEP (and every other Pythonista) has to say about it.

Comment: I'd recommend not shadowing `file`. If you're learning Python you might come across some sample code that uses it and if you add this to your script which has already defined `file` you're going to get some very confusing errors.

Comment: Ok, thanks Dave. I'll try to use a different term. I guess file is too commmon.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to open the string 'f'. Try this:

```
file = open(f, 'r')
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `f` in quotes. `f` is a variable that is holding a string, but in your open you are using the string value 'f'.

```
file = open(f, 'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

open() returns a file object, and is most commonly used with two arguments: open(filename, mode).

`>>> f = open('/tmp/workfile', 'w')`

For more Information about Files U can [Check out This Link](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html)